# AESCipher (android) vs CCCrypt(ios)

Tags: java, ios, aes

I am using 2 lib for encrypt password but with same password, i get different value:.

This is code i am using in android:

```
String dataEncrypted = new String();
try {
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    byte[] raw = hexToBytes(key);
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] byteDataToEncrypt = data.getBytes();
    byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(byteDataToEncrypt);
    dataEncrypted = new BASE64Encoder().encode(byteCipherText);
    return dataEncrypted;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //log.d(ex.getMessage());
}
```

and this code i using in ios:

```
const void *vplainText;
size_t plainTextBufferSize;
NSData *plainTextData = [data dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
plainTextBufferSize = [plainTextData length]; 
vplainText = [plainTextData bytes];
uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
size_t movedBytes = 0;
bufferPtrSize =(plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSizeAES128);
bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0001, bufferPtrSize);

const void *vkey = (const void *)[key UTF8String];


CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      vkey,
                                      kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                      NULL,
                                      vplainText,
                                      plainTextBufferSize, /* input */
                                      bufferPtr,
                                      kCCKeySizeAES128,       /* output */
                                      &movedBytes);

NSString result;
if (cryptStatus== kCCSuccess)
{
    result=[Base64 encode:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
    free(bufferPtr);

}else{
    result =@"False";
    free(bufferPtr);
}
```

How to matching 2 version of ios and android. Please help me out!

Comment: You're using PKCS7Padding on iOS what are you using on Android?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you'd want to encrypt a password on a client. Usually a hash is used for authentication.

Comment: You will certainly *always* have a different result if you use different keys.

Comment: @wilsotc: i just stay default padding on android and i always using same keys

Comment: Do you know what the default padding is? All of the parameters of the AES encryption must match. The key, padding, block size, and input text encoding (UTF8, ascii, etc).

Comment: It is not clear (to a non-JAVA programmer) what `SecretKeySpec` does. What ever it does has to be done on iOS also. Also unclear is the mode (CBC probably) and if CBC what the `iv` is. Also unknown is the padding, is there padding specified and it so is it PKCS7?

Comment: Note that I did not include the mistake of using `bufferPtrSize` to indicate the output size in my answer.

Comment: @NguyenStorm  give a complete example: All inputs to the Android encode and the output (there is probably an iv in the output. Also any other information about `SecretKeySpec` and `Cipher` that you know. Key size, mode, etc.

Comment: The problem with `SecretKeySpec` and `Cipher` is they are wrapping standard crypto primitives and not fully disclosing what primitives are being used, how they are inter-connected and their options. Basically the issues are key derivation, mode , iv (if CBC mode), data padding and any Base64 encoding. That is just completely un-professional for something such as crypto that needs to inter-operate across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The Android code is encrypting the string using AES256, and then base64 endcoding that result. The iOS code looks to be encrypting only, so to make them match you'll have to base64 encode it. Try using the following:

```
- (NSString *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *plainData = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *encryptedData = [plainData AES256EncryptWithKey:key];

    //Use any decent base64 category support
    NSString *encryptedString = [encryptedData base64Encoding];

    return encryptedString;
}
```

. . for base64 encoding use any decent category on NSString, or if you don't already have one, try [here](http://cocoapods.org/?q=base64).

**Encryption method (AES256 is the default AES on Android):**

```
   //based on: AES Encrypt/Decrypt, Created by Jim Dovey and 'Jean'
   //See http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html
- (NSData*)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString*)key
{
    uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    SecRandomCopyBytes(0, sizeof(iv), iv);

    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr )); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void* buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
            iv /* initialization vector (optional) */, [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
            buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
            &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {
        NSMutableData* result = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:iv length:kCCBlockSizeAES128];
        [result appendBytes:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];

        free(buffer); //free the buffer

        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return result;
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer
    return nil;
}
```

I've also had very good success with the [CocoaSecurity](https://github.com/kelp404/CocoaSecurity) framework, however for matching Android's AES encryption, I had to fall back to the above method. (No longer recall why).

Comment: Hmmm. Looking at your code again, I can see that you *are* base64 encoding the result. As others have pointed out the padding, etc must match. . I thought the above code matches an Android app that was using the default AES settings. Sorry it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

CCCrypt defaults to CBC mode. Java in general defaults to unsafe ECB. Please use `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` in Android and use a random IV for encryption (on Android or iOS), including the IV with the ciphertext. Note that PKCS5Padding in Java [is identical to PKCS#7 padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172). Don't rely on defaults in crypto!

Comment: Note that `getBytes()` uses the platform character encoding, which may differ per platform. Better specify that as well.